# Unfair biased coin

Tags: bias

The professor has to go to Ireland for a bonus trip and can bring with him only one student from its class. Students cannot agree on who should get chosen. One of the student produces a coin and suggests using a coin toss to determine the lucky one. None of the other students trust the coin to be fair. After a few trials, the students see that one side appears more frequently than the other, but they have not idea as to how big the bias is. The problem is to find an algorithm that simulates a fair coin toss while having access only to an unfair coin. Can you help me with this?